# SQLite3 - Wrong data stored

Tags: sqlite, lua

I got trouble with some data which get's wrong in that Database.

Trying to store a Lua String, for example:

```
foo = "1234..78.0"
```

The database returns no error. But reading the string from the SQLite 3 Database, it returns strange values, alwas with a "-" as first digit.

The Database:

```
db:exec(    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
              "Pattern("
              "Idx        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
              "Strip      TEXT,"    
              "Startdigit INTEGER," 
              "Enddigit   INTEGER," 
              "Value      TEXT,"     -- < -- THIS FIELD IS THE ISSUE
              "Name       TEXT,"    
              "Message    TEXT,"  
              "Relatives  BLOB"     
           ")"
         )
```

The write query:

```
queries.newPattern:prepare("INSERT INTO Pattern(Strip, Startdigit, Enddigit, Value, Name, Message, Relatives) VALUES( (?) , (?) , (?) , (?) , (?) , (?) , (?) )")
```

Where (?) are variables which have to be bound before executing the query by:

```
queries.newPattern:bind( idx , value ) -- binds value to (?) at (idx)th position
```

All Datatypes are correct, and the execution does not return any error.

err, errno = queries.newPattern:exec()

So err and errno are nil.

```
queries.newPattern:lastError()
```

returns nil.

Reading the Database with:

```
db:exec("SELECT * FROM Pattern")
```

Returns all data correct, except the "Value" field, which gets corrupted.

After every query, SQLites last Error is nil, so I assume there are no datatype mismatches or something.

The return value is something like(example):

```
"-1434302411"
```

What black magic is performing here?

Comment: So I found out, that SQLite is parsing the given String to numeric value. This only happens from time to time, not always. The very last line before execution command in the lua script, the value is string-type, so I guess it's the SDK which is raising that problem.

Comment: What bindings for SQLite are you using? Also you don't need to wrap the binding variables (`?`) in parenthesis.